# Adding Non clustered index

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, non-clustered-index

So the current query I have takes long time to run. When i run execution plan, it shows: Table Insert (#tempdata), Cost: 99%. I realized i need to add non clustered index to run the query fast. So I have added this line of code but still there is no difference:

```
create nonclustered index #temp_index 
  on [dbo].#tempData ([class_room]) include ([class_name],[class_floor],[class_building])
```

This is the current query I have:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempdata') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempdata

    SELECT [class_room][class_name],[class_floor],[class_building]
    INTO #tempdata
    FROM class_info x

create nonclustered index #temp_index 
   on [dbo].#tempData ([class_room]) include ([class_name],[class_floor],[class_building])

;with cte1 as(
SELECT [class_room][class_name],[class_floor],[class_building]
FROM #tempdata
WHERE class_room <> '')  

select * from cte1
```

Comment: What leads you to believe that adding a non-clustered index is going to help with insert performance here? How many rows are you putting in the temporary table? Is there a reason that you even need the temporary table?

Comment: Why are you creating a CTE if you're just going to select * from it?  Why not just select into #tempData from class_info where class_room <> ''?  Or, why create a temp table at all?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: @Tom: 9 million records

Comment: Thank you for posting the report of your current status. Was there some kind of  **question** you were going to ask?  (This doesn't seem to be related to MySQL at all; not at all clear why this is tagged with mysql.) As far as the SQL presented... *What the plastic?* Why is a temp table being created? Adding a non-clustered index isn't going to improve performance of loading the temporary table.

Comment: You really think creating an index that used once is faster than running a single table scan.  Why are you not just running the select on the table and skipping inserting 9 million rows.  This is mess up.

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit long for a comment.

Can you explain why you are not just running this code?

```
SELECT [class_room], [class_name], [class_floor], [class_building]
FROM class_info x
WHERE class_room <> '';
```

If performance is an issue, I first would recommend getting rid of unnecessary reads and writes -- such as creating a temporary table.

Comment: I guess as per an earlier question I asked, creating an index on class_room won't help. Right? Problem is "locality within indexes."